# Show closest result to current date & time (MySQL & PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm trying to make a query but after hours of trying I can't seem to get it right. What I'm trying to do is showing 1 thing from a database that is closest to the currect date & time and after the current date & time.

my columns look like this:

```
  date         time
1364399654     15:00
1364684400     16:00
1367272800     12:00
```

my PHP looks like this:

```
$timestamp_now = strtotime(date('d-m-Y')); //Creates a timestamp of the currect date
$time_now = date('H:i');
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY date ASC, time ASC (WHERE date > '.$timestamp_now.') AND (time > "'.$time_now.'") LIMIT 1') or die(mysql_error());
$data = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
```

However, this doesn't work. Any words of advice?

Comment: Please elaborate on precisely what happens, "this doesn't work" is not very helpful!

Comment: This doesn't work as in it returns empty without an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would ditch using the PHP date/time methods and rely on MySQL giving a query that looks like

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE date > CURRENT_DATE
OR (
    date = CURRENT_DATE
    AND 
    time > CURRENT_TIME
)
ORDER BY date ASC, time ASC LIMIT 1
```

The OR makes sure that it gets the correct records else the TIME portion would block i.e. a result at 03:00 from the next day from appearing if the current time was at 06:00

I see you are using timestamp values there so you can always still pass in the PHP date numeric in place of CURRENT_DATE.  This would give a final script of

```
$timestamp_now = strtotime(date('d-m-Y')); //Creates a timestamp of the currect date
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table_name 
                    WHERE date > '.$timestamp_now.'
                    OR (
                        date = '.$timestamp_now.'
                        AND 
                        time > CURRENT_TIME
                    )
                    ORDER BY date ASC, time ASC LIMIT 1') or die(mysql_error());
$data = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
```

I would advise considering changing the database if possible to store just as a MySQL DATETIME field, as then you can change this query to simply `WHERE datetime > NOW()`, but that's entirely up to you.  Just have always found MySQL date handling more logical than PHPs.

Answer (score 1):

You should use one more test :

- `DATE(date) > CURDATE()` : if it's tomorrow or later
- `DATE(date) = CURDATE() AND time > TIME(NOW())` : it it's today, but later

The full code :

```
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT * 
                    FROM table_name 
                    WHERE DATE(date) > CURDATE()
                    OR (DATE(date) = CURDATE() AND time > TIME(NOW()))
                    ORDER BY date ASC, time ASC 
                    LIMIT 1'
                  ) or die(mysql_error());
$data = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
```

Please note you're using timestamp in your `date` field. Timestamp include date **and** time, so maybe you'll be able to use this request :

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE date > NOW()
ORDER BY date ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This would lead to a table scan due to the DATE() function needing to be applied to all records to determine which match the criteria.  Additionally the ORDER is in the wrong place.  ORDER is after WHERE and before LIMIT.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the bad place for `ORDER`. For `DATE()` function, I'll let this code because it's based on the original question. I provide a better way to find the closest result at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive you need to get the SQL structured with WHERE before ORDER BY
something like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (date>$now) and (time>$now) ORDER BY date,time LIMIT 1
```