# Search SQL db and get closest time match

Tags: php, sql, database, search

I am trying to create a query to search a table for a time based on the SQL CURRENT_TIME and return the best (or closest match after) against my table. The row time is of type time. See below db snipet:

---

Station               TIME
Newport            19:00:00
Granger            19:07:00
Altonepost        19:23:00

Based on this [search sql time query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662205/show-closest-result-to-current-date-time-mysql-php) I tested several variation and found that this was a possible solution. See modified query below and if anyone has any advice, that would be great.

```
SELECT * FROM STATIONS
WHERE station = 'Granger'
   OR (time >= CURRENT_TIME)
ORDER BY time ASC
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: My question is what is the best query to use. Im im using php and mysql

Comment: What's wrong with your query?  Is it not returning your expected results?  My only suggestion would be to remove the `OR` clause if you don't want older records ever...

Comment: You are correct, its not returning the expected result. I want to get records from closest time and future records, not older. I will test without the or and see of that works. Thanks